# How to fix FileNotFoundException pdbox.cache EROFS in pdfbox

Tags: java, android, apache, pdfbox

I'm using dhorion's boxable in my android studio project. I got this error as title said.

```
BaseTable table = new BaseTable(yPosition, yStartNewPage, bottomMargin, tableWidth, margin, mainDocument, myPage, true, true);
PDPage myPage = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
DataTable t = new DataTable(table, myPage); //this line throw the exception
```

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .pdfbox.cache: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:42)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.saveDiskCache(FileSystemFontProvider.java:288)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.<init>(FileSystemFontProvider.java:226)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl$DefaultFontProvider.<clinit>(FontMapperImpl.java:130)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl$DefaultFontProvider.access$100(FontMapperImpl.java:128)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getProvider(FontMapperImpl.java:149)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFont(FontMapperImpl.java:413)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:376)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:350)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.<init>(PDType1Font.java:140)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.<clinit>(PDType1Font.java:78)
    at be.quodlibet.boxable.Cell.<init>(Cell.java:24)
    at be.quodlibet.boxable.Row.createCell(Row.java:134)
    at be.quodlibet.boxable.datatable.DataTable.<init>(DataTable.java:60)
```

Any solution?

Comment: Try setting the system property "pdfbox.fontcache" to a directory that can be written. This works for desktop pdfbox, don't know if it also works for android.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then you'll have to create an issue at https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android/ . PDFBox for desktop does check for read-only directories, although this is rather recent, this was done in issue PDFBOX-4231.